# FFmpeg 1.0 Angel --soname-prefix=PREFIX

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to compile **FFmpeg 1.0 "Angel"** with following configure :

```
./configure  --enable-gpl --enable-encoder=mpeg2video  --enable-version3 /
             --soname-prefix="/pc/temp/myproject/"
```

then compilation return following error :

```
Unknown option "--soname-prefix".
See ./configure --help for available options.
```

and when i'm running  ffmpeg/configure --help command. **"--soname-prefix"** opetion is not available in **Standard options list** but this option is available in **FFmpeg 0.11.2 "Happiness"**

Please help  me and if any new options is introduce in latest FFMPEG 1.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can't find `--soname-prefix` in `./configure` script for both versions `0.11.2` and `1.0`. But I think, if this is an option to library path, you need `--extra-ldflags="-L/your/libs"`

Comment: you known diff between `--soname-prefix` and `--extra-ldflags` .`--soname-prefix` if available in all lower version

Comment: I never used `--soname-prefix`, but i guess it's not a path definition, but prefix to library names (really don't know)? Which version is last you know, it is using this option?